# All-in-One Openstack instance network not communicate to LAN network - External-VM ping OK - VM-External/Internet ping NOT OK

Tags: networking, openstack, openstack-neutron

I just complete deploy openstack packstack all-in-one. I just follow default deployment and not edit/modified anything. I able to create instance for testing using default public network (172.24.4.0/24) or using created private network (10.0.0.0/24). So now how can I change 172.24.4.0/24 to my own LAN subnet (192.168.0.0/24) so that i can remotely access each instance within my LAN.

Do I need to redeploy everything and how to add my subnet to openstack installation for LAN access. Please help.

**by the way host ifconfig doesn't list network 172.24.4.0/24..thus i think its a standalone/isolated network...that's why VM instance not able to communicate to LAN .fyi my VM enp0s3 is using 192.168.0.18 (Lan IP)**

Thank you

---

As per advised I reinstall centos and deploy clean openstack.
I created answer file and edit below

```
CONFIG_NEUTRON_L3_EXT_BRIDGE=br-ex
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TYPE_DRIVERS=flat,vxlan
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=extnet:br-ex
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_IFACES=br-ex:enp0s3
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGES_COMPUTE=br-ex
CONFIG_PROVISION_DEMO=n
```

Deployment success and complete. I than

1. Create public external network (public-network)
2. Create a subnet (192.168.0.0/24 and pool 110-120) in this external network
3. Create private network
4. Create router
5. Attach private and public to router.
6. Create floating ip (using public-network)
7. Create new instance suing private network and attach floating ip
8. Allow icmp policy

now....
From my pc i can ping new instance vm but from vm instance I cannot ping pc and lan gw...and internet...

ip addr output below

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:98:9b:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe98:9ba3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:17:8b:e5:dc:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-ex: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:98:9b:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.121/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global br-ex
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:e68:5435:d135:a00:27ff:fe98:9ba3/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86399sec preferred_lft 86399sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe98:9ba3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-int: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1450 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:ff:0f:26:18:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: br-tun: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:52:08:a9:68:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
29: qbr1f637f14-9c: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:95:e8:c0:a3:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
30: qvo1f637f14-9c@qvb1f637f14-9c: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:2e:07:8d:79:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::6c2e:7ff:fe8d:7986/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
31: qvb1f637f14-9c@qvo1f637f14-9c: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master qbr1f637f14-9c state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:95:e8:c0:a3:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::4095:e8ff:fec0:a307/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: tap1f637f14-9c: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast master qbr1f637f14-9c state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:16:3e:05:2d:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fe05:2d50/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Try ping 192.168.0.1 (LAN GW) from qrouter and qdhcp failed , ip netns

```
qrouter-f6967bba-986e-4bb3-838e-d035a684e2c4 (id: 2)
qdhcp-dbd713cd-1af4-4e2c-9c57-d8a675a10608 (id: 1)
qdhcp-fa6fb1d6-b65e-4eb2-a4a4-5552fde8bb08 (id: 0)

sudo ip netns exec qrouter-f6967bba-986e-4bb3-838e-d035a684e2c4 ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev qg-0ba7da31-7f
10.0.0.0/24 dev qr-7e6f9436-40 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev qg-0ba7da31-7f proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.221
```

I even tried spin new vm with public-ip (192.168.0.226), my host pc can ping this VM but the VM cannot ping my host pc and internet...same problem as when using floating ip.

Based on the network image VM instances can ping up to router gw 192.168.0.221 but failed to my lan router/host pc and internet.

[image]

---

Updated-10/09

```
ip netns list
qrouter-f6967bba-986e-4bb3-838e-d035a684e2c4 (id: 2)
qdhcp-dbd713cd-1af4-4e2c-9c57-d8a675a10608 (id: 1)
qdhcp-fa6fb1d6-b65e-4eb2-a4a4-5552fde8bb08 (id: 0)
[root@myospackanswer ~(keystone_admin)]# ip netns exec qrouter-f6967bba-986e-4bb3-838e-d035a684e2c4 arp -an
? (192.168.0.211) at <incomplete> on qg-0ba7da31-7f 
? (192.168.0.227) at fa:16:3e:ed:19:81 [ether] on qg-0ba7da31-7f (Instance IP)
? (192.168.0.160) at d4:d2:52:73:de:80 [ether] on qg-0ba7da31-7f (host pc IP)
? (192.168.0.1) at 80:26:89:b2:98:50 [ether] on qg-0ba7da31-7f (home router GW)
? (10.0.0.4) at fa:16:3e:01:63:42 [ether] on qr-7e6f9436-40 (private subnet)

ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev br-ex
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev br-ex scope link metric 1006
192.168.0.0/24 dev br-ex proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.121
```

Mysetup
Windows10---Virtualbox(bridge)---HostCentos---Openstack
Wireless network.
Promiscuous mode Virtualbox (all)

**I test with different openstack release and fresh installation of OS, all same problem, cannot access LAN/Internet from VM instance. If anyone facing the same problem like me please share your solution. Thank you.**

**Just to share, I'm deploying over vmware and problem resolved. Not sure if the network problem due to virtualbox. Maybe someone could share their experience deploying openstack over virtualbox and don't have this issue (VM cannot ping external/internet)**

Answer (score 0):

`public` is indeed an isolated network that only exists on the Packstack host by default. However, you should see the `br-ex` bridge. Perhaps `ifconfig` doesn't support Openvswitch bridges; use `ip address` instead.

To connect the cloud to your existing network, try [Neutron with existing external network](https://www.rdoproject.org/networking/neutron-with-existing-external-network/) (a link to this page is at the end of the [Packstack installation page](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/)).

Unfortunately, you will have to redeploy the cloud. Actually, I would start from scratch, i.e. install Centos again.

Comment: Hmm. Can you update your question with the output of "ip a" on the Packstack host, and "ip r" on the VM? When you say that you can ping the VM, you mean its floating IP?

Comment: Yup....I attach floating ip to the VM, and my local pc ping to VM floating ip... I have update output of ip addr above.

Comment: You are sure that 192.168.0.1 is the router outside the cloud? If so, it baffles me that you can't access that address from the Neutron router. I would use tcpdump to see how packets are routed, also check the rules inside br-int and br-ex. Also check IP addresses and routing rules in the router's namespace. Currently, I have no idea what the problem might be. A shot in the dark: Is there a possibility that several devices have the same IP addresses in the network?

Comment: Yup...192.168.0.1 is my home router gw. I even flush all rules, and accept all... still not resolve... why in to out problem...really puzzl me... this is my public-subnet..my home lan range ip (confirm not use) and my home router gw 192.168.0.1..this is correct right?...===>openstack subnet create public-subnet --dhcp --subnet-range 192.168.0.0/24 --allocation-pool start=192.168.0.220,en  d=192.168.0.230 --gateway 192.168.0.1 --dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 --network public-network

Comment: ====>openstack network create public-network --share --external --default --provider-network-type flat --provider-physical-network extnet

Comment: Updated my ip netns and output above

Comment: Presumably your home router has already a DHCP server. Adding a Neutron DHCP server is not a very good idea. However, this is probably not related to your problem.

Comment: yup...Iam aware of this...and yup....i think it may not related... as I have tried nodhcp ..still same probllem....

Comment: Is it problem of virtualbox or maybe because I'm using wifi network home? I have no idea and this problem...a bit demotivated me...

Comment: I'm sure many people out there have deployed openstack over virtualbox....I dont have spare pc/host....if i have one....i will install baremetal

Comment: You know, I just have the same problem. I find that ARP requests from the OpenStack router don't get replies from the VBox router. My OpenStack host is connected via NAT Network. I am sure it's a VirtualBox problem. I created a thread in the VirtualBox forum: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=99810.

Comment: Thank you so much Berndbausch...you support and response to my inquiry and even simulate it....I hope someone in virtualbox could assist further and how to resolve this...I think this is prolong issue...just I curious why no one response or solution to this issues...I think most of us..widely use virtualbox..at least for me...(maybe got same problem..but I couldn't find them..) at least..I'm not alone....

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue. This also is an all-in-one packstack and the queens release. This was working just fine up until a few week ago. Cannot recall or find anything in my history-file pointing to a change I made.

Been spending way too much time trying to get this fixed since I have a lot of stacks deployed.

Cannot ping from my qrouter namespace to my home router.
So reason for me not reaching my instance from outside is that they cannot find their way back. Host can reach instances and instances can reach the host.

routing table of the qrouter looks fine.

Comment: My problem resolved deployd over vmware. Hope your problem resolv soon... thanks

Answer (score 0):

@chenoi As you mentioned that the problem solved when you deploy Packstack over vmware.
Currently, I have similar issue with you

```
Public= 192.168.100.0/24
Private= 10.5.5.0/24Compute node = 198.168.100.180
Instance = 192.168.100.200/10.5.5.73
qRouter = 192.168.100.186/10.5.5.1
Other machine = 192.168.100.71
```

Compute node (CentOS) -> qRouter/Instance (via floating IP) **OK**

qRouter -> Compute node (CentOS)(via public network) **OK**

qRouter -> Instance(both floating IP and private network)  **OK**

Instance -> qRouter(both public/private network) **OK**

Instance -> Compute node (CentOS)(via public network) **OK**

while

qRouter -> other machine (in same public network) **Unreachable**

Instance -> other machine (in same public network) **Unreachable**

other machine (in same public network) -> qRouter/Instance(via public network) **Unreachable**

I am not sure that my problem is relate to yours or not. however just want to try that.

PS. My Compute node is running of ESXI7 with Promiscuous mode but i could not find where i can change NIC to bridge mode.

thks.